# How to remove mosaic lines between images with gdal

Tags: gdal, mosaic, sentinel1

Maybe this is a simple issue but I couldn´t find a solution for it. I used gdal (gdal merge, and also trying with buildvrt and translate) for mosaic 8 sentinel 1 images in osgeo4w shell and it seems fine except when I zoom in and find white lines where the stitch was made, please see screenshots below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnebe.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf0dx.png)

Have been looking for possible solutions within gdal tools and its parameters, but so far nothing worked. Saw something mentioning a -cbind but not sure how to apply it, that is, if it is really useful in this case.
If someone can help, I´d really apreciate it.

Thanks.